# What is "module" in the docstring of len?

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
>>> print(len.__doc__)
len(module, object)

Return the number of items of a sequence or mapping.
>>> len(os, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Notice the *two* parameters in the first line of the docstring.

When would you pass two arguments to `len`? Is the docstring incorrect? I'm using Python 3.4.0.

Comment: For me, `print(len.__doc__)` prints **len(object)

Return the number of items of a sequence or collection.**

Comment: @falsetru That's weird. Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4.2

Comment: `3.4.1 (default, Oct 11 2014, 04:40:31) \n[GCC 4.7.3]` here, also have no `module` in the docstring.

Comment: I can also reproduce with `Python 3.4.0 (default, Mar 17 2014, 23:21:47)`.

Comment: @rightføld: Perhaps you should show us what `print(len)` produces.

Comment: @NedBatchelder "<built-in function len>"

Comment: Seems to be a Python 3.4.0-specific bug, then.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue21294

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a bug submitted on 2014-04-18 [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue21294). It has since been fixed in 3.4.1.

Quoting Vedran Čačić, the original author of the bug report:

```
From recently, help(len) gives the wrong signature of len.

Help on built-in function len in module builtins:

len(...)
    len(module, object)
        ^^^^^^^^
    Return the number of items of a sequence or mapping.
```

Comment: [Python 3.5.0 alpha 1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1836) also contains two arguments in `len()`'s docstring, but the docstring is slightly different and the module object is not being used at all.